# Trouble with converting an array of strings into an array of objects-JSON.parse

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, e-commerce

I know this is not horribly difficult based on what I've been reading, but I keep getting an error msg. Generally something along the lines of an unexpected identifier.

https://gist.github.com/2869105

The gist shows all relevant info but I'll add the main js here.

```
- content_for :javascripts do 
  - cache('search_autocomplete') do
    :javascript
      $(function(){
      var products = #{auto_complete_products.to_json};
        $("#keywords").autocomplete(products,{
        appendToElement: ".autocomplete"
          });
      });
```

This is how it is currently set up. I want to convert this array of strings to an array of objects, as I will be adding an image along with the current name when autocomplete occurs.

Rails 3.0.7
Mac OS X Lion
HAML/SASS

Note the second file in the gist is what I tried, but did not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the autocomplete feature this way: `$('#keywords').autocomplete({source: array_or_hash_or_path})`.

So I guess you need something like this:

```
$("#keywords").autocomplete({source: #{auto_complete_products.to_json}})
```

Comment: Hi jdoe, I appreciate the answer. However autocomplete is not the issue at hand here. I just need it so it is returning auto_complete_products as an object, not as a string. And fairly certain it has to do with JSON.parse, just can't get the syntax correct.

Comment: I've pasted you an example that is 100% working. If your `auto_complete_products` returns an array of strings, then calling `to_json` on is enough. Just pass it as `source` "parameter" in your autocomplete call an it should work. I've changed my snippet accordingly.

Comment: Excuse my noobness but I just don't see what you have essentially done differently. In my case there is products, merchants, and product sources (and images come from product sources). product and merchant names are combined and sorted uniquely, now I need to tie in images somehow. Which I was trying with `product_source_image = ProductSource.find_by_name("Target").image(:thumb)`. Then when I try to add product_source_image in here `(product_names + merchant_names + product_source_image).order(:name)` I get a `can't convert String into Array` error message. Not trying to waste your time.

Comment: Maybe it was confusing but the search bar/autocomplete was working fine when I started this user story.

Comment: @DavidPardy It was the first time you'd mentioned `product_source_image`. Here's what caused your error: `product_names` and `merchant_names` are Arrays, but `product_source_image` is just a String. You can't add string to arrays via `+` operator -- all items has to be of the Array type. The simple workaround here: replace `product_source_image` with `[product_source_image]`. So the result will be `(product_names + merchant_names+[product_source_image]).uniq.sort`.